# Retrieving More columns as Part of VSTS query

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to fetch details from VSTS using VSTS query API. So to get all Portfolio Epics I created a custom query and used its ID to get that in JSON format. the query looks like this

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql/{id}?api-version=5.0-preview.2
```

But the issue is its not giving me many details about each of the work items in JSON. It only lists the ID and URL. Like this

```
WorkItems:[
    {ID:234,URL:"workitemurl"},
    {ID:235,URL:"workitemurl"},
    {ID:236,URL:"workitemurl"},
    ...
]
```

So if I need more details about an item I need to execute those individual URl for each PE and thus I can get its details. instead of I am just checking is there is any way of getting an ID (keyedinID of each work item along with the ID and URL) like this. Please note KID is a field if we execute the URL separately. So to avoid that extra process, I would like to get that along with the WorkItems.

```
WorkItems:[
    {ID:234,URL:"workitemurl",KID:002},
    {ID:235,URL:"workitemurl",KID:023},
    {ID:236,URL:"workitemurl",KID:033},
    ...
]
```

So how can we make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The Web UI uses a different API to get query results (`/_api/_wit/_query`), which allows query+data in a single pass. This is an old `__v5` type call, which means it's considered internal.

The proper way to do this now is to first do the query as you're doing it right now and then call `/_api/wit/workitems?ids=1,2,3,4` using the IDs from the references you got from the first call. That will also allow you to load the details dynamically and in small batches which will result in a more responsive UI.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1

Comment: Thanks a lot Jesse. But my concern is if there are more than 1000 IDs it will be difficult this way.. Hope you got me... So what Im thinking is, is there is some way for getting all workitems under a query with that query.. something like that.. :) Not sure there is some method existing..

Comment: The whole idea is that since http allows parallel connections you can fetch the 1000 work items I'm parallel batches. You didn't mention the technology you use to perform this request, but c#, Javascript and other languages have good support for patterns like these.

Comment: Sorry friend, I missed to mention.. Im using Alteryx Designer... Thanks a lot for that information..

Comment: I have no knowledge of that tool or how to solve this issue there. That would be a separate question that takes this as a prerequisite.